# Database Bloqueada Sqlite3, Python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Con este módulo pretendo traer los datos de una tabla a otra y luego cambiar los campos fecha que están almacenado como string en formato '15/03/2023' deseo cambiarlos a '2023/03/15', todos los campos fechas para luego usarlos como tipo fechas, lo único que se me ocurre fue este código, leer cada campos convertirlo y luego guardarlo convertido, pero me genera un error, se bloque la base de datos. ¿Me pueden ayudar a descubrir el error?, ¿hay otra manera de hacerlo mejor?

```
def exportar_temporal(self):
    self.mifecha_linea=StringVar() 
    query ='INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTOS (Fecha_movi, equipo_movi) SELECT fecha, Numero FROM temporal'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query) 

    query = 'SELECT * FROM MOVIMIENTOS' 
    db_rows = self.run_query(query) 
    for database_movimientos in db_rows:
        self.miid_movi=(database_movimientos[0])
        self.mifecha_linea.set(database_movimientos[1])
        self.mifecha_arribo.set(database_movimientos[7])
        self.mifecha_patio.set(database_movimientos[9])

        #Convertir fecha a formato Date()
        self.mifecha_linea11 = datetime.strptime(self.mifecha_linea.get(), "%d/%m/%Y") # Convierte en datetime
        self.mifecha_linea1=self.mifecha_linea11.date()
        self.mifecha_arribo11 = datetime.strptime(self.mifecha_arribo.get(), "%d/%m/%Y") # Convierte en datetime
        self.mifecha_arribo1=self.mifecha_arribo11.date()
        self.mifecha_patio11 = datetime.strptime(self.mifecha_patio.get(), "%d/%m/%Y") # Convierte en datetime
        self.mifecha_patio1=self.mifecha_patio11.date()

        query1 = 'UPDATE MOVIMIENTOS SET FECHA_MOVI = ?, FECHA_ARRIBO_MOVI = ?, FECHA_PATIO_MOVI = ? WHERE ID_MOVI = ?'
        parameters1 = (self.mifecha_linea1, self.mifecha_arribo1, self.mifecha_patio1, self.miid_movi)
        self.run_query1(query1, parameters1)
```

Esta es la consulta

```
# Consulta
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
    #return [rec for rec in result]
```

Este el el error que me sale

```
C:\Container>menucontainer.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py",    line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Container\menucontainer.py", line 688, in exportar_temporal
   self.run_query1(query1, parameters1)
  File "C:\Container\menucontainer.py", line 2509, in run_query1
    conn.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo. Cierra los recursos que no estés usando. En tu caso, `cursor.close()` es tu amigo.

```
# Consulta
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
    return result
    #return [rec for rec in result]
```